# android, button and checkboxes results

Tags: android, string, if-statement, button, checkbox

Just want to start off saying I am fairly new to coding for android but I am trying my best.

What I'm trying to do is have multiple results happen when multiple check boxes are checked.
its kind of hard to explain the code might help a bit more

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    Checkbox cb1, cb2;
    Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cb1 = (findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    cb2 = (findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    b1 = (findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3 = (findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b4 = (findViewById(R.id.b4);
    b5 = (findViewById(R.id.b5);
}

@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

if (cb1.isChecked()) {
    b1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey));
    b2.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey));
    b3.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey));
}
if (cb2.isChecked()) {
    b3.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey));
    b4.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey));
    b5.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey));
}
else {
    b1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green));
    b2.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green));
    b3.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green));
    b4.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green));
    b5.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green));
}
}
```

so basically I'm trying to get it so if only Checkbox 1 is checked, we see the background of buttons 1-3 change and if only checkbox 2 is pushed then buttons 3-5 are changed, and if both are pushed then all buttons are changed. This I am achieving no issue.

The problem I'm having is trying to get them to revert.
so for example say I have both cb1&2 checked then I uncheck cb2 the field stays as if cb1&2 are pushed, I'm trying to get it so when cb2 is unchecked the result for only having cb1 checked comes back (buttons 4 & 5 would change back to green)

I've checked all over the internet for this and cant find a answer or at lease a path to point me in the right direction.

I tried to use a "switch/case" set up which didn't work (found out why after) then I tried to loop the switch, again didn't work.
I tried using a else if statement then I found out that's basically the same thing as a switch
I thought about maybe using a string array but I'm not 100% sure if that would have the desired result.

I still have my code from the failed switch/case attempt if that is needed

Comment: I suggest setting a breakpoint inside `onCheckedChanged()` and run your app in the Android Studio debugger. Then you can step through the code to see what is happening.

Comment: Also, there is no reason for `ContextCampt.getColor()`, you can just do `setBackgroundColor(R.color.grey)`.

Comment: Hint: use two separate `if...else` statements rather than trying to combine them in some way.

Comment: I tried using the 2 separate if else statements, for some reason it kept skipping the first if else statement, when cb1 was check, all the buttons remained green, but when I added cb2 into it the code to run both was there

Comment: The devil is in the details. Two separate if...else statements are definitely needed here. I can't be sure why your previous attempts weren't working without more information. As I said in my first comment, you will need to debug your code to get a deeper understanding about what is going on. [Here is an article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) that can help with some general tips. Hopefully this debugging will help you come up with ideas of how to fix it to do exactly what you want.

Comment: It might help to take a step back from the code and write in words what you want the behavior to be. For example, "if checkbox 1 is selected then ... otherwise ...". Fill in the blanks. Write a similar sentence for checkbox 2. Then check your verbal description with your code to make sure they match up.

Comment: Ah okay I shall give that a shot I was thinking it would be if else statements I just couldn't get it working, ill put them back in as that and see what I can get working

Comment: Thank you for your reply:)